# Page Height Equal Window Height

Tags: javascript, css

After two days of research, I still can't find a solution. I'm using an image as the background to my bootstrap 2.3.2 site. I'm trying to figure out how to get the browser window to adjust to the height of each page. At first the background image was visible below the footer, which looked pretty stupid. All attempts at background-overflow: hidden; didn't work when applied to body or to the style sheet for the image.  This is the code for the script that sorta worked:

```
`    <script type="text/javascript">
 var viewport = $(window).height();
 $('.container-fluid').height(viewport);
 </script>
```

`
This got the image within the confines of the body, but produced scrolling no matter how high the browser window. This is the code being used for the image:

```
body {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
background: none;
background-overflow: hidden;
}

.full {
 background: url(http://test2.gandlconsultants.com/assets/img/big-pic-01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 999;
 }
```

Could someone please tell me how to get the browser window to limit itself to the actual height of the page i.e. if page is only x number of pixels the browser window adjusts to the x height of the page. The page I'm writing this on does that. Thank you.

Comment: What does your basic HTML look like?

Comment: Do you mean the window resizes based on the height of the page ? Lets says your page finished half way the borwser window then should the browser window be half size too ?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">

Comment: Yes, Norman that's what I mean.  Rachel, thanks for the response, but your suggestion did not help. I was using html class-full.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
body {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
background: none;
background-overflow: hidden;
}
```

to

```
body {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
background: none;
height: 100vh;
}
```

and

```
.full {
 background: url(http://test2.gandlconsultants.com/assets/img/big-pic-01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 999;
 }
```

to

```
.full {
 background: url(http://test2.gandlconsultants.com/assets/img/big-pic-01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100vh;
 z-index: 999;
 }
```

Note:  `background-overlfow: hidden` is not a valid css maybe you mean `background-origin: border-box;`

Comment: Thanks Tambo.  Your solution didn't change anything though.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which element did you apply the `.full` class to show the background in your document. If it is not on the body tag, I suggest you add the following to the the CSS class:

```
 position: relative;
 height:100%;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Oluwatumbi, but this didn't solve the problem.